# Error receive push notification when app is in minimized : Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework

**When we receive a push notification on the app while the app is momentarily in the background, we get this error:
Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE**

We have seen that with the android sdk 31, the minimum version that can be used and is compatible with regard to firebaseMessaging is 20.2.4.

**We fixed this by increasing the version value from 20.1.2 to 20.2.4.**

[image: variables.gradle]

Comment: The solution is to increase the version of firebaseMessaging.                                                     I solved it like this in my case

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do or what plugin you are using. I'm not an expert on android, but I think this error happens when you are trying to create an intent fired when the notification arrives.

**1. In case you are using Capacitor:**

I recommend you to use this plugin: [push-notifications](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications). You won't have problems with it.

**2. In case you can edit the notification android code:**

You should have a function like `PendingIntent.getActivity(...)`. In that function, you have to add `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE`.

Example of the result:

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, PENDING_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE++, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
```

This is the function to create intent that I use in case it's useful for somebody:

```
    private static PendingIntent createIntent(Context context, Map<String, String> data) {
        Intent intent = context.getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName())
                .setPackage(null)
                .setAction(context.getResources().getString(R.string.intent_filter_action_fullscreennotification_trigger))
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        if(data != null) {
            for (var entry : data.entrySet()) {
                //System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
                intent.putExtra(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, PENDING_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE++, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    }
```